# Show that if b is a positive number and a < b, then a/b < ( a+1 / b+1 )

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Show that if $a < b$  and $b$ is a positive number, then

$\frac ab$ < $\frac {a+1}{b+1}$

Comment: Did you try cross multiplying?

Comment: I did, but ended up with a(b+1) < b(a+1), and ab + a < ab + b. Then I got a < b. Would this be the correct way to complete the proof? I just feel like there's more..

Comment: That's not but almost a proof. You just have to write things backwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is equivalent to showing $\frac{a+1}{b+1}$-$\frac{a}{b}>0$. Simplify $\frac{a+1}{b+1}$-$\frac{a}{b}$  to get $\frac{b-a}{b(b+1)}$. The denominator is positive since it is given that $b$ is positive. The numerator is positive since the assumption is that $b>a$. Hence  $\frac{b-a}{b(b+1)}>0$

Answer (score 0):

This is simply seen by cross multiplying:
\begin{align*}
\frac{a}{b} &< \frac{a+1}{b+1} \\
\Leftrightarrow a \cdot (b+1) &< (a+1) \cdot b \\
\Leftrightarrow a \cdot b+a &< a \cdot b + b \\
\Leftrightarrow a &< b \\
\end{align*}

The last line is a thing we already know.
Notice that $b$ and $b+1$ are positive, which is why we can crossmultiply without turning the $<$ into a $>$.

Comment: You should put $\iff$ everywhere.

Comment: user236182 Yes, I was just looking for a way to put it in latex. Still not satisfied with the formating.